# Mysql selecting values from 2 tabes

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "articles" which has a column called article char and photo_ID int.

And I also have a table called photos.

It has 2 columns photo_ID and photo_name.

I need to select photo name from table photos, but take its ID from table articles.

I tried this, but I'm doing something wrongly.

Can someone help?

The code is:

```
CREATE TABLE articles(Article CHAR(35) NOT NULL, Photo_ID INT(5) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE photos(Photo_ID INT(5) NOT NULL, Photo_name CHAR(35));
INSERT INTO photos VALUES
(1, "one.png"),
(2, "two.png"),
(3, "three.png");

INSERT INTO articles VALUES
("one", 1),
("two", 2),
("three", 3);

SELECT Photo_name 
  FROM photos 
 WHERE articles.Photo_ID = photos.Photo_ID = 2;
```

And the last select doesn't work. I get error Unknown column 'articles.Photo_ID' in 'where clause'

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select is wrong  you need  a proper join and a proer where clause

```
   SELECT photos.Photo_name 
   FROM photos 
   INNER JOIN articles ON  articles.Photo_ID=photos.Photo_ID
   WHERE photos.Photo_ID=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Proper select & join with where clause.

```
  SELECT p.Photo_name 
  FROM photos p
  LEFT JOIN articles a ON a.Photo_ID=p.Photo_ID
  WHERE p.Photo_ID = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the table articles the same way you are using a database, so you can't call articles.Photo_ID in your WHERE clause.

try instead

```
SELECT Photo_name FROM photos WHERE photos.Photo_ID=2;
```

and this should work.

when you specity FROM photos, don't call articles.Photo_ID because the table articles is not loaded.

So if you want to load the article table, you should try doing a JOIN ... ON ...

like

```
SELECT article, photo_name FROM photos LEFT JOIN articles ON articles.Photo_ID = photos.Photo_ID WHERE articles.Photo_ID =2;
```

Maybe this is new stuff for you, there's 4 type of JOIN : LEFT, RIGHT, INNER, OUTER.

Okay I hope this helps.

Ciao

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Join` tables.

```
SELECT p.Photo_name FROM photos p
JOIN articles a
ON p.id = a.Photo_ID
WHERE p.id=2;
```

P.S Better to change column names

| articles |
| --- |
| id |
| article |
| photo_id |

| photos |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

```
SELECT p.name FROM photos p
JOIN articles a
ON p.id = a.photo_id
WHERE p.id=2;
```